# Expectation of a combinatorial extremal random variable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, metric-embeddings

Consider the finite set $\chi(D)$ of all sets of integer points in $\Bbb Z^n$ around origin which have distance at most $D$ from each other and pick a set $\mathcal P(D)$ from set of sets $\chi(D)$ with the largest cardinality uniformly.

Consider the set $\mathcal T(K,d,\mathcal P(D))$ of set of all $K$ distinct points in $\mathcal P(D)$ that are distance at least $d$ from each other where $d< D$. This set is a list of $K$-tuples where each $K$-tuple is a set of distinct points in $\mathcal P(D)$ such that pairwise distance of the points is $D$ and no $K$-tuple occurs twice in the list in any permuted form.

Pick a $K$ point set $\mathcal U$ from $\mathcal T(K,d,\mathcal P(D))$ uniformly.

Fix $K'$ and $d'$ such that $d\ll d'<D$ and $0<K'\ll K$ holds.

The number of ways to choose $K'$ points from the set $\mathcal U$ such that pairwise distance of the $K'$ points is at least $d'$ apart is a random variable $v(K',d')$ (ignoring dependence on $K,D$).

What is the expectation of this random variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\mathcal{P}(D)$ is **the** finite set of integer points...?" Is it a ball around the origin? Or an arbitrary set of points with small pairwise distances? When you say "distance," are you talking about Euclidean distance, or something else? When you say "mean of each $K$ distinct points" you mean like the center of mass, I guess?

Comment: @JonNoel It is Euclidean distance. The structure of $\mathcal P(D)$ is unclear but I think it is a ball.

Comment: just arithmetic mean.

Comment: What do you mean that you "think" its a ball? The question was asked by you ;-). Can you clarify what $\mathcal{P}(D)$ is supposed to be?

Comment: @JonNoel $\mathcal P(D)$ is what I defined but it is hard to see what it is geometrically.

Comment: The definition doesn't seem to be unique. There are many sets of points which are at pairwise distance at most $D$ from each other, not a unique one. (for example, just two points at distance $D$ would be such a set). Or do you mean that $\mathcal{P}(D)$ is as large as possible with respect to this property, or something?

Comment: @JonNoel we can pick uniformly from that set as well.